# javascript regex rule problem

Tags: javascript, regex

```
function checkVideoUrl(url){
    var regex= [],urlmatch= false;

    regex[0] = /http:\/\/www.56.com\/\S+\/([^\/]+).html/i;

    for(i=0;i<regex.length;i++){
      urlmatch =regex[i].test(url); 
      if(urlmatch == true) break;
    }
    return urlmatch;
}
alert(checkVideoUrl('http://www.56.com/w68/album-aid-8529817.html'));//true
alert(checkVideoUrl('http://www.56.com/u96/v_NTQ5MTM1ODE.html'));//true
```

how can i match http://www.56.com/u96/v_NTQ5MTM1ODE.html only.

thanks a lot.

Comment: Unsuccessfully resisting answering with `return url === "http://www.56.com/u96/v_NTQ5MTM1ODE.html";` **;-)**

Comment: Speaking seriously: You haven't given people enough information to work with. What is it about the second URL that makes it a match when the first one isn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `v_` indicates that it's a video URL:

```
/http:\/\/www.56.com\/\S+\/v_([^\/]+).html/i;
```

This will also capture the `NTQ5MTM1ODE` part, which is probably the video ID.

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother with regular expressions when they aren't needed...

```
function checkVideoUrl(url)
{
    return url == "http://www.56.com/u96/v_NTQ5MTM1ODE.html";
}
```

Comment: I have seen the error of my ways and will try to correct them